# Error #1064 MySQL when i try to insert register with my API

Tags: python, mysql, json, api, flask

i have a problem with syntax when i try send method post using python. This is my python function:

```
def insert_tipo_falla(self,cod_falla,desc_falla):
        sql = 'INSERT INTO TipoFallas(cod_tipo_falla,desc_falla) values ({},{})'.format(cod_falla,desc_falla)

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            self.connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            raise
        finally:
            self.connection.close()
```

Sending with my API this json:

```
{
    "cod_tipo_falla":"104",
    "desc_falla":"TAP NIVELES BAJOS"
}
```

This function send a error when i try to insert with my API:

raise_mysql_exception
raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NIVELES BAJOS)' at line 1")

I check several times, i insert manually way and it works, but using this python function dont it works
Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the query that is formed and you could see the error if you try printing the query. You need to quote the text while inserting.

From :

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO TipoFallas(cod_tipo_falla,desc_falla) values ({},{})'.format(cod_falla,desc_falla)
```

To:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO TipoFallas(cod_tipo_falla,desc_falla) values ({},"{}")'.format(cod_falla,desc_falla)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use placeholders instead

```
def insert_tipo_falla(self,cod_falla,desc_falla):
        sql = 'INSERT INTO TipoFallas(cod_tipo_falla,desc_falla) VALUES (%s,%s)'

        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql,(cod_falla,desc_falla))
            self.connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            raise
        finally:
            self.connection.close()
```

Comment: i have similar code i visual studio code with the actual python 3.9.6, and it works fine and it follows the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html